# Why do I need to supply any arguments to Flask-SQLAlchemy's Column constructor?

Tags: python, database, flask-sqlalchemy

In the [basic examples](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/models.html) of Flask-SQLAlchemy usage to define data models, type and other attributes of each column are specified; but much of this seems redundant and appears in fact to be ignored.

For example I seem to be able to replace

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
```

with nothing but the specification of the `primary_key`

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column()
    email = db.Column()
```

or even values that don't correspond to the underlying database table

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=False)
    email = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=False)
```

and still get a model that corresponds to the database (as specified in the first example).

Are any of the arguments to `Column` necessary for an existing database? If not, what purpose do they serve (especially since they seem to be ignored)?